# Powershell Scripting Variables

Tags: powershell, variables

I have set some variables in PowerShell. The variables are created at the beginning of my script. However, the values for the variables are being executed at start which in turns gives and error message. Ex:

```
$checker = get-item -path C:\users\user\desktop\Foldername
$finder = Test-path -Path $checker
if($finder -eq $finder )
{

}
Else
{
  Create-Item -Path C:/users/user/desktop -name "Foldername" -itemtype Directory
}
```

I do know that if I run this it will give me an error because the directory never existed and I can just change the variable order to avoid errors.

My question is that this script is going to be more lines of code than this and I would have to create the variable right when its needed to avoid errors.

How can I use these variables like a regular programming language where the variables are ignored until called upon.

Comment: Why do you compare `$finder -eq $finder`? If you compare a variable with itself, it will always be true. If the variable throw an error, either correct the variable or catch the error. I am pretty sure if a variable in another language is incorrectly instantiated, it would also throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Get-Item` and checking with `Test-Path` afterwards is not a good design. Two better ways:

1. Use `Get-Item` only and check for `$null` to check for its existence:

```
$checker = Get-Item -Path C:\users\user\desktop\Foldername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($checker) {
    # do something with the existing folder
} else {
    Create-Item -Path C:/users/user/desktop -Name "Foldername" -ItemType Directory
}
```

2. Use `Test-Path` only to check for its existence:

```
if (Test-Path -Path C:\users\user\desktop\Foldername) {
    # do something with the existing folder
} else {
    Create-Item -Path C:/users/user/desktop -Name "Foldername" -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I apologize for the late reply. I have another question. What is the best case uses for powershell when supporting end users.

Comment: @FernandoB Both are valid solutions.